# how should we remove duplicate array from 2D array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've array like this

```js
const data=[ [aa, bb, cc], [aa, dd, cc], [aa, bb, cc], [aa, ee, cc], [aa, ff, cc], [aa, dd, cc]]
```

I want to convert it into like this:

```js
const data=[ [aa, bb, cc], [aa, dd, cc], [aa, ee, cc], [aa, ff, cc]]
```

I tried like this:

```js
var unique = data.filter(function(elem, index, self) {
  return index === self.indexOf(elem);
})
```

but it's not working properly.

P.S. thank you.

Comment: Your code currently results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: aa is not defined @ JS line 1`. Are the `aa`, `bb`, etc, variables, or strings? If strings, they need string delimiters

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the values by composing a key based on the JSON value. With they key, you can build a map contain unique JSON keys. Once you have looped-through the data, return the values of the map.

```js
const data = [
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ee', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ff', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc']
];

const unique = [...data.reduce((cache, curr) => {
  let key = JSON.stringify(curr);
  if (!cache.has(key)) cache.set(key, curr)
  return cache;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(unique.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)).join('\n'));
```

Here is an example a cloning into a set. Both this and the previous example are naive solutions. Serializing and deserializing the values will perform poorly on larger data sets and item types.

```js
const data = [
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ee', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ff', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc']
];

const unique = [...new Set(data.map(x => JSON.stringify(x)))]
  .map(x => JSON.parse(x));

console.log(unique.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)).join('\n'));
```

Alternatively, here is a function that lets you define your keying function. The default will serialize the entire item as seen in the examples above. Passing in your own keying function offers the ability to improve the way you serialize your keys.

```js
const uniqueItems = (items, keyFn) => {
  keyFn = keyFn || (item => JSON.stringify(item));
  return [...data.reduce((cache, curr) => {
    let key = keyFn(curr);
    if (!cache.has(key)) cache.set(key, curr);
    return cache;
  }, new Map()).values()];
}

const data = [
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ee', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ff', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc']
];

const unique = uniqueItems(data);

console.log(unique.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)).join('\n'));
```

Finally, if you want to do this in real-time, and modify the array in-place, you can splice items with a backing set.

```js
const uniqueItems = (items, keyFn) => {
  keyFn = keyFn || (item => JSON.stringify(item));
  const keys = new Set();
  let index = 0;
  while (index < items.length) {
    const key = keyFn(items[index]);
    if (!keys.has(key)) {
      keys.add(key);
      index++;
    } else items.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return items; // Original; modified
}

const data = [
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ee', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'ff', 'cc'],
  ['aa', 'dd', 'cc']
];

const unique = uniqueItems(data); // unique === data

console.log(unique.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)).join('\n'));
```